# How to reduce the times of build broken in software development?

Tags: build-process

I am in large product that there are more than 200 people and locate in 3 different locations.  Most of people work on the main branch , so of course, it is important to void the build broken.  There is an daily build and it will take about 6 hours to generate the build. 
Manage team emphasis "taking care before submit" again and again, but now it is at least one build broken during one week.

Would you share your practice to reduce the build-broken? Thanks.

Comment: What versioning system do you use Git, SVN, other?

Comment: Seriously? 200 people in 3 locations, 6 hours to build and you are coming to SO for a solution? Surely one of your 200 workers should have some clue about basic software engineering practices...

Comment: 6 hours is too long. Break dependencies in your software and build smaller increments of your software more frequently. Add verification steps after each increment builds.

Comment: Also, make sure each build action is only happening when it (or a dependency) has changed.

Comment: Going along with EthanB's suggestion, the master branch should not be the main development branch.  You should review your branching strategy as well asimplement some code review before it's merged into the master branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broken build should become a not-Event, to achieve this you need to reduce the costs associated with broken build, right now because it takes 6 hours to create it and most likely it executed during time when majority of people are out of office every broken build can move a schedule of entire project of by a day. To remove this cost you need to build often and build quickly. So the best thing you can do is to improve build times and build on every check-in.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do would actually be to try as hard as possible to make the build faster. The importance of this cannot be understated - just have quicker builds is probably your fastest and biggest win. At least put SSDs on your build machine.

That aside, here are some things I've seen done:

- Partial builds: also called smoke tests by some people. High level tests that run fast and fail the whole build quickly. They'd run before the full build.
- Smaller local builds: With that many people, I'm guessing you have some kind of local branch for each set of programmers. Do you have a build that runs locally there?
- Make sure developers run the widest possible set of tests on their own machines before pushing code. This already happens... right?